# JavaScript Game - Logicmistake

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am writing a little computer game using JavaScript canvas. (for me its a quite big project)

[image: Screenshot]

as you can see, I am making a game, where a stickman (in the moment just a green box) is able to move through a scene. (and there is an hp and mp bar too)

this grass is generated using a SINUS-FUNKTION. This is the Code for the grass:

```
// this function is called every frame.
function drawGrass() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    var countDetailGrass = 0;

    ctx.moveTo(0+player.x+WIDTH/2, HEIGHT-200);
    ctx.beginPath();

    for(var i=0; i<WIDTH+options.grassResolution; i+=options.grassResolution) {
        ctx.lineTo(i-player.x+WIDTH/2, HEIGHT-200+Math.floor(Math.sin(i/12)*3));
        countDetailGrass++;
        drawDetailGrass(i-player.x+WIDTH/2, Math.floor(Math.sin(i/12)*3), countDetailGrass);
    }

    //for(var i=0+player.x; i<WIDTH+options.grassResolution; i+=options.grassResolution) { ctx.lineTo(i-player.x, HEIGHT-200+Math.floor(Math.sin(i/12)*3)); }
    //for(var i=0; i<WIDTH+options.grassSteps; i+=options.grassSteps) { countDetailGrass++; drawDetailGrass(i-player.x, Math.floor(Math.sin(i/12)*3), countDetailGrass); }
    //for(var i=0-player.x+WIDTH; i<2*WIDTH+options.grassResolution-player.x; i+=options.grassResolution) { ctx.lineTo(i+player.x-WIDTH, HEIGHT-200+Math.floor(Math.sin(i/12)*3)); }
    //for(var i=0-player.x+WIDTH; i<2*WIDTH+options.grassSteps-player.x; i+=options.grassSteps) { countDetailGrass++; drawDetailGrass(i+player.x-WIDTH, Math.floor(Math.sin(i/12)*3), countDetailGrass); }
    ctx.moveTo(WIDTH, HEIGHT); ctx.moveTo(0, HEIGHT); ctx.moveTo(0, HEIGHT-200);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawDetailGrass(pos1, pos2, count) {
    count += Math.floor(Math.sin(count/100)*20);
    while(count > 4) { count -=4; }
    while(count < -4) { count +=4; }

    switch(count) {
        case 1 || -1:
            ctx.fillRect(pos1, HEIGHT-200+pos2-5, 1, 5);
            ctx.fillRect(pos1+1, HEIGHT-200+pos2-10, 1, 10);
            ctx.fillRect(pos1+2, HEIGHT-200+pos2-7, 1, 7);
            break;
        case 2 || -2:
            ctx.fillRect(pos1-4, HEIGHT-200+pos2-3, 1, 3);
            ctx.fillRect(pos1-2, HEIGHT-200+pos2-4, 1, 4); 

            ctx.fillRect(pos1, HEIGHT-200+pos2-9, 1, 9);
            ctx.fillRect(pos1+1, HEIGHT-200+pos2-7, 1, 7);
            break;
        case 3 || -3:
            ctx.fillRect(pos1, HEIGHT-200+pos2-3, 1, 3);
            ctx.fillRect(pos1+1, HEIGHT-200+pos2-2, 1, 2);
            ctx.fillRect(pos1+3, HEIGHT-200+pos2-4, 1, 4);
            break;
    }
}
```

my question / problem is: how can I make this grass infinite? so, that I can "walk" (changing player.x) infinite to the left and right?

I already tried that a few times (the comments) but failed.

Can somebody help me?

Some additional info:

- **WIDTH** and **HEIGHT** are the *width* and *height* of the canvas
- **player.x** has as standard *WIDTH/2*
- **options.grassResolution** is variable, which exists of performance reasons. It saves an integer, it has the standard *15*. That means that just every 15 pixel the sinus funktion is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much trig you know, but sine is a cyclical function, with period 2π. If you add an offset to the argument, the whole wave "moves" left or right depending on the sign. So the quickest way to draw this would be something like this

```
for x:=0 to width   // canvas width
  line(prevx, sin(prevx+offset), x, sin(x+offset));
  prevx:=x;
```

So just draw it from 0 (left) to `width` (right), segment by segment. The `offset` parameter is how much your character moved (if I understand correctly he's supposed to sit in the middle, so the grass is the one that actually moves).

Comment: I don't know enough to understand you. I don't know what an "period" is (in this case)

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if it would be the best way to do it, but you could create a step counter and associate it with the player sprite movement. Just re-render your grass with every refresh, treating the middle of the player's sprite as x == step count (so you are rendering a window of a Cartesian plane rendering of your grass function from whatever the lower and upper bounds of the canvas element happen to be). As a bonus, this will give you something to pass to other functions if you want to create events at certain points in the game.

In effect what you are doing is changing how you think about what's moving. The sin wave which your grass is built on will be moving relative to the player sprite which is effectively the center of the little world you are creating.